# Python- compare dictionary values (list) and get key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures

I have a dictionary `EllipseDict` of length `len(EllipseDict)=309`, I need to compare the values and return tuple of keys which have an intersection. This is the code I have written, it takes about `52.43 seconds`. Can anyone suggest any improvements to this code ?

```
checked = []
intersectingEllipses = []
for k1, v1 in EllipseDict.items():
    for k2, v2 in EllipseDict.items():
        if k1 == k2:
            continue
        else:
            if (k1, k2) and (k2, k1) not in checked:
                checked.append((k1, k2))
                common = set(v1).intersection(v2)
                if len(common) != 0:
                   intersectingEllipses.append((k1, k2))
```

Comment: Fix your if condition...  `if (k1, k2) and (k2, k1) not in checked:` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @tehhowch Do you mean: `if (k1, k2) not in checked and (k2, k1) not in checked:` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compound if statement with an `and` is interpreted like so:

```
if [condition A] and [condition B]
```

Now take a look at your if statement:

```
if (k1, k2) and (k2, k1) not in checked
```

This is true when:

- `(k1, k2)` is truthey (this is your `[condition A]`) AND
- `(k2, k1)` is not in `checked` (this is your `[condition B]`)

What you probably meant was to check that the two tuples (`(k1, k2)` and `(k2, k1)`) are not in `checked`. For that, you need to change your condition to:

```
if (k1, k2) not in checked and (k2, k1) not in checked
```

Now your conditions are

- `(k1, k2)` is not in `checked` AND
- `(k2, k1)` is not in `checked`